# Spring Boot - Reactive MongoDB: Random Access in GridFS?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, gridfs

How to random access chunks (start from any specific chunk, not necessarily from the first) in GridFS in Reactive MongoDB in the Spring Framework?

With the `ReactiveGridFsTemplate` available since `Spring Boot 2.2` I cannot see any way.
Is there any low level method to do it?

**NOTE:** I opened a feature request in [Spring Data Mongo Jira](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAMONGO/issues/DATAMONGO-2441?filter=allopenissues&orderby=created%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC)

Comment: How about [this](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-data-mongo-gridfs/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java) ?

Comment: How I can access e.g. chunk#10 with this example?